# Convert image from gallery to bitmap. I get a NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I'm trying to convert an image from the gallery into a bitmp and then store it in an array. Previously, however, I am getting a NullPointerException.
How can I convert the image from the gallery?

AddNewHomeFragment.kt:

```
...

else if(requestCode == GALLERY &&  resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null)
    {
        //imgData = "content://media/external/images/media/100051...
        val imgData = data.data!!
        val inputStream = requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(imgData)

        val exif = ExifInterface(inputStream!!)

        val rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED
        )
        val rotationInDegrees: Int = exifToDegrees(rotation)

        //ERROR THROWS HERE
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)

        val bitmapReturn = rotateBitmap(bitmap,rotationInDegrees)
        listImg[aktuellesBild] = bitmapReturn!!

        adapter.notifyItemChanged(aktuellesBild)
    }
```

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: bitmap must not be null**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reuse `inputStream`. `ExifInterface` will have consumed the stream already. You need to call `openInputStream()` again to get a fresh `InputStream` to pass to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`.